# Convert Int value to Decimal $

Tags: java, android

I've already tried a way to format this whole number in decimal plus no solve the one that comes closest to the result hoping was using the BigDecimal plus it was very extensive. Where am I going wrong?

```
Double value = 20852;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
String result = df.format(value);
```

result = 20852.00

expected outcome : 20.852

Comment: Have you tried dividing by 1000? You know...basic math.

Comment: DecimalFormat doesn't format the number, but the display. Since you have a value of 20852, it will display you that number, following the specified format. It won't, however, transform the number.

Comment: BTW, are you wanting to use the period `.` as a decimal separator, or between thousands and hundreds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With decimal format you define how many decimal places are need to be set. The output is completely correct. It would create the desired output if you have `double value = 20.852`. What you want is to set the thousand sepeator:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##", symbols);
```

Comment: how do I limit the decimal places after the point?
Example: 20.852 to 20.85 I already tried reducing the # more did not work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by your question, without changing anything to your number and to get the result your expressively required, you *could* do this with setting the ***dot character as a thousands separator*** :

```
    Double value = 20852d;
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##,000", symbols);
    String result = df.format(value);
```